# Can I retrieve phone number with Microsoft and Google oAuth?

Tags: google-oauth

I viewed here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?csw=1

there are reference to PhoneNumber in the response, is this actually possible, I went to their playground but could not find any phone number in the response of contacts, before moving on to a live implementation I would like to be sure phone numbers are retrievable.

As to Microsoft, I couldn't find any reference to phone number retrieval from oAuth, anybody knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to see phone numbers when I run a query against Google's implementation.

I did notice that the initial results (first 25 only) didn't appear to have any, but once I dumped all my contacts (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=99999) I was able to see the results that I'd expected.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/1.0/elements#gdPhoneNumber